# Some basic Azure Questions

Tags: asp.net, azure, cloud

I'm currently in the process of building our ASP.NET C# 3.5 Web site and I have been looking at Azure as our possible hosting environment and I had a couple of questions that I couldn't really find answers for on their website. I would appreciate if someone could help me get these figured out.

1) If I setup a single cloud server with my ASP.NET application & SQL server database, and the server went down, Would my application automatically get brought over to a new cloud server and continue to run? Or, am I required to manually move the data over to a new cloud server?

2) In the future, when I need to maintain more instances to handle the load, How hard is it to configure the database and sessions to work across all of the instances?

3) Do I still get remote desktop access on the cloud servers?

4) Are there any other cloud hosting provider that you would recommend over Azure for Windows hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, there is automatic failover and backup
2. You change a number in a config file, and click save
3. Not currently
4. I haven't done a ton of research, but Azure is pretty impressive.  It all depends on what your needs are.

Comment: 2) Is it really as simple as changing a number in a config file?  I was under the impression that it would be more difficult than this.  How do you make sure that each given user stays on the same server that their session is on?

Comment: It is magic, more or less ;)

The service keeps track of it for you.  The point is that you don't have to manage a cluster, but you get the benefits.

Comment: Wow, that is great!  I can't wait for it to roll out in January!

Answer (score 0):

If you're a powershell guy, you can write a powershell to swap out the config files for you, there's a pretty good walk through to do that here: http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Azure/Deployment/DeployingApplicationsinWindowsAzure/Exercise-2-Using-PowerShell-to-Manage-Windows-Azure-Applications/

If you're a cmd file guy, you can use the csmanage.exe to swap config files, downloadable here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazuresamples.